# the problem is still return object not title and how to add in reference models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def _str_(self):
        return self.title
```

I am trying use str to return the title but unfortunately it returns back object 1

Answer (score 1):

## conventions

`__bar__`:  a way for the Python system to use names that won't conflict with user names.

`_bar`: a way for the programmer to indicate that the variable is private (whatever that means in Python).

`__bar`: this has real meaning: the interpreter replaces this name with `_classname__bar` as a way to ensure that the name will not overlap with a similar name in another class.

No other form of underscores have meaning in the Python world, so you should use `__str__` nor `_str_`

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

### Other examples:

`__init__()`, `__call__()`, `__add__()`, `__new__` ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to user double underscore (__)

so it'll look like:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```